# Restarting Nginx after SSL keys update

Tags: ssl, nginx

After updating SSL keys which I use for Nginx to serve HTTPS, should I restart Nginx? Is it enough to send it SIGHUP signal?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247418/do-i-need-to-restart-nginx-if-i-renew-my-security-certificates

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to restart nginx to use your new certificates.

I'm not sure about SIGHUP signal, but you can take a try easy :)

Comment: The question asked for a yes or no answer, and he answered it very concisely.